# RMarkdown .yml file for Github Pages compiling a removed page

Tags: r, github, r-markdown, github-pages

I actually have 2 problems, but I suspect one might be caused by the other, so I will lay out the whole shibang.

I have a personal site I created in Rmarkdown and host with Github pages. Everything was going fine, and I was adding new content to the site until I updated R, RStudio, and my packages (I know, I know). One of the pages on my site generates a simulation and uses the simr package, and after I updated my packages I kept getting the following [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/euk93.png)

To try to fix this problem, I

(1) Uninstalled/reinstalled simr,

(2) referenced the simr package when I called the powerCurve function (e.g., simr::powerCurve), and

(3) just tried to remove the page from my website by commenting out the file on the .yml page.

When I tried to compile the site after commenting out the reference to the broken page, I noticed that R was still trying to compile the broken page. So I *deleted* the reference to the broken page on .yml, but it *still* tried to compile it.

What am I doing wrong? Ideally I'd like to be able to fix the broken page and continue adding content, but at this point I would be just as happy if I were simply able to remove the broken page. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to get the simr package to work. However, I was able to remove the broken page from my site. After commenting out the reference to the broken page on the .yml page, I then went into the broken page and deleted all the code (after saving the contents elsewhere). It appears that the change that included only commenting out the broken page did not trigger an evaluation of the change by Github, so the revision of the page itself caused Github to reference the .yml page and prevent the broken page from being evaluated.